# Ошибка при запуске сайта на IIS

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть проект MVC4 который прекрасно работает в Visual Studio, однако когда я пребрасываю на IIS сервер, при загрузке страницы, на которой есть операции с базами данных, происходит ошибка. Либо ошибка авторизации пользователя(например "ASP NET 4.0", который является дефолтным в пуле ASP.NET 4.0), либо когда я в пуле ставлю пользователя, с которого я собственно работаю на компьютере, появляется криптографическая ошибка `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Ошибка при выполнении криптографической операции.` Ошибки происходят в одной и той же строке(с обращением к БД).

Пользуюсь MS SQL Express, Visual Studio 2012

Как я и говорил ранее через студию все прекрасно работает. Я подозреваю что ошибка именно в `connectionstrings`, но понять в чем конкретно не могу.

Connection string:

```
<add name="ContentDb"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ContentDb; Integrated Security=SSPI"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

AppPool Settings:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы используете сертификаты в проекте?

Comment: @tCode, сам сертификаты не делал, как это проверить?

Comment: я имею в виду вы в коде не используете класс X509Certificate2?

Comment: @tCode нет, не исользовал

Comment: стектрейс в студию. Из него будет хотя бы понятно на каком этапе ошибка.

Comment: И попробуйте использовать авторизацию SQL вместо встроенной. Для сайтов со встроенной очень много мороки - если только вы не делаете  сквозную авторизацию на всех уровнях, тогда встроенная конечно же обязательна.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вы используете WIF? Во всяком случае нижеприведенный модуль должен решить проблему.

```
public class CryptographicErrorModule : IHttpModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// You will need to configure this module in the Web.config file of your
    /// web and register it with IIS before being able to use it. For more information
    /// see the following link: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=8101007
    /// </summary>
    #region IHttpModule Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //clean-up code here.
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.Error += ContextOnError;
    }

    private void ContextOnError(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context == null)
            return;

        var error = context.Server.GetLastError();
        var cryptoError = error as CryptographicException;

        if (cryptoError == null && error.InnerException is CryptographicException)
            cryptoError = error.InnerException as CryptographicException;

        if (cryptoError == null)
            return;

        if (context.Request.Cookies["CryptoErrorOccured"] != null)
            return;

        context.Response.Cookies.Clear();
        var cookieCount = context.Request.Cookies.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < cookieCount; ++i)
        {
            var httpCookie = context.Request.Cookies[i];
            if (httpCookie != null)
            {
                var cookieKey = httpCookie.Name;    

                var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieKey)
                {
                    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), 
                    Value = "",
                    Path = httpCookie.Path,
                    Domain = httpCookie.Domain,
                    Secure = httpCookie.Secure,
                    HttpOnly = httpCookie.HttpOnly
                };

                context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
        }

        var cryptoErrorCookie = new HttpCookie("CryptoErrorOccured", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("G"))
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)
        };

        context.Response.Cookies.Add(cryptoErrorCookie);
        context.Server.ClearError();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: как не странно, но по просшествии некоторого времени все само собой почиилось, черт его знает в чем проблема была

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте SSPI изменить на true:

```
<add name="ContentDb" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ContentDb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

можете скинуть скрин ошибки?